# Symfony2+Doctrine2: How to properly localize records?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, internationalization

I'm looking to manage record localization with Doctrine on the Symfony2 framework.

Requirements are

- ability to translate records
- ability to add a record in one locale only
- a developer-friendly reusable pattern of any kind to accomplish this

So far I have implemented the [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) library to make use of the `Translatable` extension. Everywhere I read it is regarded as the preferred way of handling translations. I realize this is not the same as localization but it seems this is the closest I was going to get.

Let's say I have a product table with translatable products. My default language is english. After I insert a product in the default english locale I can later add a translation to let's say italian.
What I haven't been able to do with the Translatable extension is to only add a product in the Italian locale. If I do that, the Translatable extension also adds the product in the default language (english) but with italian content. And then it proceeds to also add an italian translation.

My product entity looks like this; (simplified)

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="acmedemobundle_product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    protected $name;
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to add a record in a non-default language *only*? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

-

Before using Symfony&Doctrine, I was used to managing localized data in two tables which were then joined together using the requested locale.

For example, the `products` table contained all  locale-indepent data like

- id
- category_id

and the `products_i18n` table contained all localized data like

- product_id
- locale
- name
- description
- slug

This way, there is only one main record which can be used for relations, and one or more localized extensions. A record without a localized extension would be seen as nonexisting.

Perhaps there is a way to accomplish that instead?

-

To be honest, so far I haven't found much useful information at all on this specific subject. I can't imagine I'm the first to come across this issue.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

==============
**UPDATE**

I decided to go with a custom solution that ties two tables together like I illustrated in my example above. Main reason for this (besides I needed the functionality) is that `Translatable` saves ALL translated data in a single table. This doesn't feel right from both a performance and crisis-scenario point of view. Much more organized to have each table's localized data in it's own table rather than aggregated.

For now, I accepted Peter's answer since it was the most helpful. If a better answer comes along, I will consider switching. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be a bit of a source of misunderstanding. When you want to make products only available in certain regions (based on the locales ), you are not asking about the translation being only available based on a locale.
It is pretty perfect that the doctrine extension insists on providing a default translation for your product, otherwise your application won't be able to handle request properly.
After all, the product is available in all regions or locale zones, so how to provide the information for the translated content, say, name?
If there is no default settings for the translated name, this means the product displayed within the default zone can't resolve its name. The entity is incomplete as the name would be null. 
To add the product to a certain locale zone only, you would have to add a property to your product, as

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $localeZone;
```

which then gives you a posssibilty of filtering entities.
You also could setup your Entity Product as a MappedEntity and use several Subs for Local entities, this would give you a change of storing products for italy in ItalianProducts , e.g. though I would not personally like this thought, as it is a distinguishing of objects based on the value of an property therein it, rather then a difference in behavior or data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My whole point is to make records *not* available in all locales. As long as Doctrine doesn't mind, my app would have no worries handling it. But I'm not set on a specific solution, as long as it is possible to get this to work. I don't see your idea working in the long run, any time a locale is added then I'd have to add a boatload of entities.

Comment: The first approach is based on an additional property within the existing entity. Filtering can easily be done based on a repository impementation as implementing methods like "findAllProductsByLocale()". The property doesn't have to be exposed in forms, but instead could be inserted by the controller handling the form. As Symfony 2 supports urls based on locales, the locale - string is a paramter easily retrieved by the framework. So this approach is quiet easy.

Comment: The other way is teaking into the Doctrine Extension to change the default behavior of it regarding the doubled insert into both default and speficified locale which will then leave the extension being no more updateable. This is like hacking the Symonfy - Core.

Comment: If you take a look at https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Document/Translation.php you will find that translations are handled via a MappedSuperClass. Translations are stored behind the scenes and your entity is wrapped into an https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Translator/TranslationProxy.php . So while there are ways to provide an own implementation of the https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Translation.php

Comment: without modifying the extension itself there is no way of specifying: only entities of a certain locale should be available. You got to implement that at the application layer.

Comment: Another way would be to check if another than the default locale is stored in the database and discarding access when this locale doesn't match the users locale, e.g. not providing them into the listed links for products or pulldowns. This would not modify your Entity - class, still this is to be implemented at the application layer. I personally would prefer the approach of introducing an additional property into the entity though this seems to be introducing a redundancy, because the handling on which entities made available would be cleaner.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty. Wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but very helpful none the less. I decided to go with a custom solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the award. I am sorry, that these are the only possible solutions to your problem domain. But  after all:It won't take too much time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Translatable behavior extension for Doctrine 2](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md)

Comment: As stated in my question; the `Translatable` is what isn't working for me. Unless u think I'm using it incorrectly, but then please elaborate on what it is that you think I should be doing differently.